# Editor tipo DateTime no muestra la fecha pero en el input si aparece el valor

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en ASP.Net MVC5 que contiene un padrón de trabajadores, entre los datos que se deben capturar está la fecha. Ahora el problema es que en mi vista Edit si me carga el valor que proviene del modelo en el input, no obstante en diseño no me lo muestra. Aqui les dejo primero la imagen de mi página de edición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que está marcado en rojo debería traer los datos de la fecha de nacimiento. Si me meto al código de fuente de la página veo que el valor si se carga en la propiedad value del input pero no se visualiza en el control

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a continuación el código en razor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia de que estoy haciendo mal?. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, ya intenté varias soluciones que vi en foros y ninguna me soluciona le problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar la fecha y hora en un componente HTML debes usar un **input** de tipo **date** y pasarle el valor formatado de la siguiente manera:

```
año-mes-dia
```

> **Nota:** El día y el mes deben de tener **dos** dígitos y el año **cuatro**.

Por ejemplo, si quieres mostrar el 1 de febrero de 2018 quedaría así:

```html
<input type="date" value="2018-02-01">
```

Comment: Llevaba horas buscándole ja ja ja ja. Gracias, eso resolvió mi problema.

Answer (score 3):

Podrias ver de usar algo como esto

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaNacimiento, new { @type = "date" })
```

pero el formato lo aplicas por medio del atributo en el model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime FechaNacimiento{ get; set; }
```

[How to use Html.TextBoxFor with input type=date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086909/how-to-use-html-textboxfor-with-input-type-date)